# SSRS line graph: x-axis time-scale with gaps in data

Tags: reporting-services, axis, scalar

I have a dataset which counts the number of produced pallets per hour, eg

11/11/2010 22:00  --> 22
11/11/2010 23:00  --> 12
11/12/2010 00:00  --> 18
11/12/2010 01:00  --> 19
11/12/2010 03:00  --> 20

As you may notice, there is a gap between 01:00 and 03:00 since there is no data for that hour. This data gets visualised in SSRS 2005 using a graph with a time-scale x-axis. When the graph type is 'Column', there is no problem at all since 02:00 gets visualised with no (0) value and the gap is well visible in the graph. When the graph type is 'Line' or 'Area', 02:00 is visualised on the graph as well but with no 0 value: there is a connection line between the value of 01:00 and 03:00. When looking to the line graph, one could conclude that there was production at 02:00 but this is not true, it is just the line that connects the value of 01:00 with the value of 03:00.

Example of the same data in an Area graph [image](original image: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/9616/area.jpg)

and a Column graph [image](original image: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/7590/column.jpg)

should explain the problem.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: are you reporting from a SQL datasource, and if so, which version of SQL - Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you have found an answer to your question now. This is for others who might stumble upon this question. This solution is only applicable if you are using **`SQL Server 2005 or above`** as the data source for the reports. The example uses `Common Table Expressions (CTE)` to achieve the desired results mentioned in the question. The example mentioned below uses `SSRS 2005` and `SQL Server 2008 R2` database. CTEs are supported in `SQL Server 2005 or above`.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create a table named `dbo.TimeScaleData` and populate with the data provided in the question. Refer screenshot #**1**. Create scripts of the table is provided under **SQL Scripts** section.
2. Create a CTE that will take the minimum and maximum date values in the table  `dbo.TimeScaleData` and generate all the time values for every hour between the given range. Then use `OUTER APPLY` between the CTE and the table `dbo.TimeScaleData` to fetch the data. Any time range that doesn't have a matching record will be assigned the value 0. Refer screenshot #**2**. This query will be used in the SSRS report to create the dataset. The query is provided **SSRS DataSet Query** section.
3. Screenshot #**3** shows that the CTE query is being used to create the report dataset. Screenshots #**4** - #**7** shows how the Chart control is configured to use the dataset.
4. Screenshot #**8** shows the report output against the data in SQL Server table.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeScaleData](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeValue] [datetime] NULL,
    [PalletsProduced] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TimeScaleData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**SSRS DataSet Query:**

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime  AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @EndDateTime    AS DATETIME;

SELECT  @StartDateTime  = MIN(DateTimeValue)
    ,   @EndDateTime    = MAX(DateTimeValue)
FROM    dbo.TimeScaleData;  

WITH CTE(DateTimeRange) AS
(
        SELECT  @StartDateTime AS DateTimeRange
    UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, 1, DateTimeRange)
        FROM    CTE
        WHERE   DATEADD(HOUR, 1, DateTimeRange) <= @EndDateTime
)
SELECT          CTE.DateTimeRange
            ,   COALESCE(TSD.PalletsProduced, 0) AS PalletsProduced
FROM            CTE
OUTER APPLY     (
                    SELECT  PalletsProduced
                    FROM    dbo.TimeScaleData TSD
                    WHERE   TSD.DateTimeValue = CTE.DateTimeRange
                ) TSD;
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

Comment: I had found a solution but not quite the same as the one above. Thanks, I'll try to implement this!